# Why doesn't \pitchfork symbol work?

Tags: symbols, texmaker, input, amssymb

I want to use the `$\pitchfork$` symbol to denote transversal intersection, but when I compile my code, it does not appear. So for example, `$\Gamma \pitchfork W$` just comes up like `$\Gamma W$`. I am using Texmaker.

Would appreciate any help to resolve this issue.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{authblk}
\pdfoutput=1
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools, cuted}
\usepackage{lipsum, color}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

Consider $\Gamma \pitchfork W$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have the required packages loaded? Please show a MWE.

Comment: Sorry I am not very experienced with tex. What is MWE? @TeXnician

Comment: A MWE is a minimal working example, a minimal compilable document reproducing your error, you would post here.

Comment: Will edit my post above @TeXnician

Comment: I think you'll need package `amssymb`

Comment: @Texnician: You have been faster ...

Comment: @Jürgen But I was too lazy to write an answer ;)

Comment: @Alex Not only nothing is printed, but you also get an error message when running LaTeX on your file. Never disregard error messages: this one tells you that `\pitchfork` is undefined. The linked questions has pointers for finding out what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `\usepackage{amssymb}` it works (at least for me).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{authblk}
\pdfoutput=1
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools, cuted}
\usepackage{lipsum, color}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

Consider $\Gamma \pitchfork W$

\end{docum
```